# Getting Camtasia for Windows to record pc/software's audio

Tags: screencasts, camtasia

I'm building a screencast of a web app / game we've built. Its got audio integrated.

I've downloaded Camtasia for Windows. The audio sources I can choose in option have grayed out the option for the source from PC.

Anyone have any luck troubleshooting this?

Comment: Dear OP:  What worked?  Or did you give up?

Answer (score 0):

May want to make sure Windows is seeing your microphone correctly first.  In XP it's: Control Panel, Sounds and Audio, Voice.

Also, I found [Fraps](http://www.fraps.com/) to be a lot simpler to use than Camtasia. Then again, I'm not a very demanding audio/video capture user.

Comment: Yea, for gameplay videos Fraps is currently the "best" I'd say. It's definitely worth its money. I use it.

Answer (score 0):

Fraps is really the best for Game Play recording :)

Camtasia is really good for screen cast , but I think you should by Snagit instead, both from one company . But you'll get screen capture from Snagit :)

Record with sound is really easy with these ones . You should check your microphone :)

Answer (score 0):

Vista disable the sound and microphone options of your system by default you need to right click on your speaker icon (taskbar) select recording devices > right click and show disabled devices. This will allow you to turn on the option to record your computers sound.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial on their help site titled "[How do I record system audio? (The sound that comes out of my speakers)](http://www.techsmith.com/learn/camtasia/6/faq/system-audio.asp)". You may want to see if this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  The greyed out option changed however when I changed my headset from a typical 3.5mm input to a USB model.  I can now record from the system audio.